# Laravel Eloquent doesn't want to save itself on DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, routes

So here it is, I'm trying to make an email confirmation system. Everything is very simple, when creating the account, an account and a token are created and an email with a link containing the email address and the token is sent to the email address used to create the account. The links contained in the email bring back one on a route in GET which has as parameter the email address as well as the token and this route executes a function in a controller and what this function does is mainly to check if the account is already confirmed, if not, it checks if the token is valid and if it is, it changes the value of "emailConfirmed" from false to true. It is able to set itself to true, that is not the problem. The problem is that it does not send this new value of true to the database

**Here is the function in my controller:**

```
public function confirmMail($email, $theToken)
{
    $user = ZUser::where('email', $email)->take(1)->get()[0];

    if ($user->emailConfirmed == false) // If email is not confirmed
    {
        $token = Token::where('email', $email)->where('token', $theToken)->first(); // Get the line where there is the same email and token then in the URL

        if (!is_null($token) || !empty($token)) // If $token is not null or not empty, so if the query found something
        {
            $user->emailConfirmed = true;
            try
            {
                $user->save();
            }
            catch (Excpetion $e)
            {
                return response()->json(['message'=> "Error while saving", 'success' => false, 'status' => "Request Failed", 'id' => null], 400);
            }
            return response()->json(['message'=> "The value of emailConfirmed is $user->emailConfirmed", 'success' => false, 'status' => "Request Failed", 'id' => null], 400);
        }
        return response()->json(['message'=> "Cannot confirm the email, non-existent account", 'success' => false, 'status' => "Request Failed", 'id' => null], 400);
    }
    return response()->json(['message'=> "Email already confirmed", 'success' => false, 'status' => "Request Failed", 'id' => null], 400);

}
```

**Here is my route:**

```
Route::get('/confirm/mail/{email}/{token}', [ControllerUser::class, 'confirmMail'], function ($email, $token) {})->name('confirmMail');
```

**Here is an example of the mail (it is the correct link the the confirmation page):**
[image]

**Here is the result of the confirmation page:**[image]

**Here is the data in the database after "confirming" the email (emailConfirmed is still at 0):**[image]

I am really lost, I don't know why it isn't working since I did the same thing to be able to "create" an account, I had to execute a save on the DB. What can I do the solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The problem was related with the primary key. In my model I had `protected $primaryKey = 'iduser';`but in my migration the name of the field was actually `$table->id('idUser');` so I change my primary key in my model for `protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';`